# Alamofire Xcode 8 Swift 3 results in 786 compile errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire

I am using the Xcode 8.0 GM. I created a default single-view app with my deployment target set to 9.0.

In my Podfile I'm targeting the bleeding edge Swift 3 branch:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProject' do
    pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'swift3'
end
```

I run `pod install` and get ... `Installing Alamofire (4.0.0-beta.2)` ... fantastic, no problems. I open `MyProject.xcworkspace`.

This pops up:

[image: convert Alamofire to latest syntax]

I can't hit later because it tells me:

> Xcode 8 will not be able to build the target “Alamofire”, and certain editing features will not function properly until the Swift source code in this target has been converted.

That's no good, I want to build it. So I hit "Convert". It gives me options:

[image: convert to Swift 3]

Well that's what I want, Swift 3. Looks good, I hit "next".

[image: select targets]

It defaults to these 3 selected targets. Ok fine, I hit next.

[image: error 1]
[image: error 2]

What in God's Holy name...

I want to use Alamofire's `swift3` bleeding edge branch on an Xcode 8, Swift 3 project targeting iOS 9.0. Where did I go wrong and how can I get this working? FWIW I get a bunch of errors trying to use Alamofire's Swift 2.3 branch so I know it's something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: ask alamofire developers for a version that supports Swift-3, please don't use Xcode convert tool.

Comment: Their swift3 branch supports Swift 3. That's what I don't understand.

Comment: that's weird, maybe we should wait for them several days :(

Comment: I don't think it's them I think it's something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: what if not selecting it ?

Comment: did you use the correct toolchain version to use Swift 3 ?

https://swift.org/download/#previews

Comment: There is a bug in the latest XCode 8's where a build will randomly fail, listing hundreds of errors that actually don't exist. When I see this I just build again and they go away. I've reported it to Apple.

Comment: Its unbelieveable how XCode behaves. Makes a completely stable product development cycle go down the drain. Completely untrustwrothy.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest Cocoapods (at the time of this answer: version `1.1.0.beta.2`) via the command:

`gem install cocoapods --pre` 
seemed to solve the issue for my circumstance.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I've updated Cocoapods to 1.1.0.beta.2, tried to install Alamofire again, but it is still not working for me...

Comment: @Rados You should check what version of Cocoapods is used with `pod --version`. The older versions are still there being used so you could use `gem cleanup`to keep only the latest release of Cocoapods.

Comment: It was a problem with Xcode itself (I was using Xcode 8 beta 6). When I downloaded Xcode GM everything went as expected.

Comment: Thanks, it help me very much!

Comment: This did nto help, itfact it got worse. I got 4 errors on this line of code ` urlSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration)`

Answer (score 7):

I was able to get it working:

update:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'PROJECT NAME HERE' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Alamofire',
    :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git',
    :branch => 'swift3'

end
```

pod update Alamofire

[It should update to 4.0.0-beta.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnd2t.png)

There are a few changes when getting a request:

old:

```
Alamofire.request(URL_NAME_HERE, withMethod: .get).responseJSON { response in
     //Code here.
}
```

new:

```
Alamofire.request(URL_NAME_HERE, method: .get).responseJSON { response in
     //Code here.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: They specifically mention to write a question on Stack Overflow and tag it with the "Alamofire" tag. I almost put sentence in my original question expecting an answer like this.

Comment: What did you do when the "Convert to current Swift syntax" prompt appeared when you opened the project? And you're using Xcode 8 GM?

Comment: I never converted. Yeah, Xcode 8 GM (Been using swift 3 for awhile now). If you have converted, revert back to your working copy.

Comment: I was able to create and build a new project. I'm going to assume you are opening the "xcworkspace" after you have installed the pod? See Podfile update above. Thats what I'm using line for line. No problems.

Comment: That's strange. It automatically shows that prompt when I open the project. So you created a new empty project, created a podfile with those specs, ran pod install, then reopened the xcworkspace and it didn't prompt you at all and worked? It always prompts me to convert the target "Alamofire" to the latest swift syntax after I `pod install` then open the xcworkspace.

Comment: Correct, and it never asks me to convert the syntax.

Comment: I wish I could accept this as the answer if only I could reproduce your steps and get it to work.

Comment: While your answer didn't solve my issue it indirectly helped me diagnose it with the sample project you linked. I gave you an upvote for good measure as it technically could be considered a solution.

Comment: Thanks. I completely forgot about the Cocoapods 1.1.0.beta.2

Comment: There is no branch called swift3

Comment: After swift 3 official release there's no swift3 branch anymore. You have to use instead:
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => '4.0.0-beta.2'

but there are 404 issues...

Answer (score 7):

You should use the `master` branch now since the `swift3` branch has been merged there. Moreover it's normal for the Xcode Migrator to show that many errors. What it's doing s compiling the code thinking it's a legacy Swift version but since it's already in Swift 3.0, the errors are to be expected. Finally, Xcode is asking you to convert to modern Swift syntax probably because you haven't used the latest version of Cocoapods to install Alamofire.

NB: event though Cocoapods tells you to use `gem install cocoapods --pre`, I prefer using `gem update cocoapods --pre`. Else, the older version of Cocoapods stays and still is used when using `pod update`. Check what version you're using with `pod --version`.

Answer (score 4):

Update the pod to 1.1.0.rc using the below command.

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

use the blow snippet at the end.

`post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end`

this helps.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to change your request from this

```
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'swift3'
```

to this

```
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'master'
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar issue by using

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
```

in the pod file. I did have to adjust to a higher minimum deployment target.

Answer (score 2):

I solved similar issue by using :

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'PROJECT NAME HERE' do
pod 'Alamofire'
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I uninstalled cocoapods, uninstalled alamofire, then updated my cocoa pods to 1.1.0.beta.2, then used the swift3-rebased branch of Alamofire in my pod file

`pod 'Alamofire',
    :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git',
    :branch => 'swift3-rebased'`

opened my *Project*.xcworkspace file and all the compiling errors for Alamofire were gone.

Comment: well scratch all that, its now cocoa pods 1.1.0.rc.1 and Alamofire 4.0 now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps anyone but just in case..
I tried to add Alamofire to a sample quick app on Xcode 8.0 GM using the CocoaPods standalone app.. I kept getting the Convert to swift 2.3 or 3.0 window.. but then I tried from the command line to pod update and it worked. Have no idea why.. I assume the underlying commands for the standalone app are the same.. so not sure what made the difference. In any case after 30 minutes of wasted time mine works.

[image: CocoaPods standalone Mac app screenshot]

This is the command line screenshot.. same pod file

[image]

Comment: Easy: the CocoaPods App uses the release version of CocoaPods tool (1.0.1) which doesn't take Swift 3 into account whereas you've probably already updated the command-line tool to one of the pre-release 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to use version 4.0`pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'` 
notice that CocoaPods 1.1 is needed.