# Migration to swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire, swift3

I am trying to migrate to swift 3.

1. I have already updated the podfile with the latest version of
   libraries written in swift 3.
2. I have updated the cocoapods as for
   Alamofire as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39384526/848377).
3. I have run pod install and pod update
4. I have cleaned the build folder and also performed project clean.

Still I keep getting `Dependency Analysis Error` for Alamofire. Also I keep getting the pod frameworks in the targets to convert even when I have already updated the pods.

[image]

Note that I have already converted my source code successfully into swift 3.
[image]

Comment: Have you set the deployment target to iOS 9.0 or greater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Build Settings, set Use Legacy Swift Language Version to No if you use swift3  in xcode8

Answer (score 1):

In Build settings > add `SWIFT_VERSION` and set to `YES`

[image]