# Alamofire 4.0, Swift 3 AFError.Swift

Tags: swift, cocoapods, alamofire, xcode8, ios10

Background:

I am relatively new to programming and am updating my current iOS project which uses Alamofire & Swift 3. The project was working fine until I updated to Alamofire ~4.0 which presented me with 530 errors.

I'm opening up the xcworkspaceproject in Xcode8.1

I tried clearing up the problem using the suggestions in this StackOverflow Thread: [Alamofire XCode8 Swift 3 results in 786 Compile Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380939/alamofire-xcode-8-swift-3-results-in-786-compile-errors)

including:

```
gem install cocoapods --pre
```

and also downgrading the cocoapod version `cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.1` from the current beta version down to `cocoapods-1.1.1`

I also: 1. Deleted the podfile 2. created a new podfile   3. reinstalled all the pods 4.) Clean & Build

Unfortunately none of these worked.

Displayed Errors:

```
Type 'AFError' does not conform to protocol 'RawRepresentable'
```

Most of the other of the 530 errors are:

```
Definition conflicts with previous value
```

[image]

All the errors are contained within the AFError.Swift file (which is locked by default). Thanks for any solution to help in fixing this.

Comment: If the error is use of undeclared type `Error`, it means your project is still in 2.x version

Answer (score 1):

a. Try installing your pods using a stable version after a deintegration:

```
`pod deintegrate && pod _1.1.1_ install`
```

b. Try purging DerivedData cache: close Xcode (fully close, like with cmd+q), delete the DerivedData folder, empty the trash. And only re-open Xcode after that last step, to correctly re-build the cache.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This was able to get it working. I did have to delete the podfile from the project also but now it is fixed :)